# How fix wpml with labels?

Tags: wordpress

my question is how can I translate labels in Wordpress plugins?

```
// single product page message
array(
    'title'    => __( 'Single Product Page Message', 'woocommerce-points-and-rewards' ),
    'desc_tip' => __( 'Add an optional message to the single product page below the price. Customize the message using {points} and {points_label}. Limited HTML is allowed. Leave blank to disable.', 'woocommerce-points-and-rewards' ),
    'id'       => 'wc_points_rewards_single_product_message',
    'css'      => 'min-width: 400px;',
    'default'  => sprintf( __( 'Purchase this product now and earn %s!', 'woocommerce-points-and-rewards' ), '<strong>{points}</strong> {points_label}' ),
    'type'     => 'textarea',
),
```

This is a label in the Adminpanel, but how can I fix it with wpml? Because wpml dont get that information.

Comment: Try running the string scan for themes and plugins.

Comment: I did, but it doesn't change the label

Comment: So on string translation page you are getting the translation option for this label. You added the translation and it is not appearing on front end?

Comment: No, because the string takes the input of the label in your adminpanel.